# Describe destructed property with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

If I do like this I can desribe my property and get intellisense when later using myObject (using Visual Studio Code).

```
/**
* @type {MyObject}
*/
const myObject = object.nestedObject.myObject;
```

But what if I destruct an object like this

```
/**
* @type {MyObject}
* @type {MyObjectTwo}
*/
const { myObject, myObjectTwo } = object.nestedObject;
```

How can I use JSDoc to understand this way of assigning properties (deconstructing an object) so that I can get intellisense on `myObject` and `myObjectTwo`?